# How to cascade an update from "PUT" method so that all tables in the mysql many-to-many relationship are updated?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, entity-framework-core, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to update 3 tables in my database from a single PUT method.  On my web page I create JSON and send it to the Web API in a PUT method.
The PUT method is the default method generated by vs2017:

```
// PUT: api/Engineers/5
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PutEngineer([FromRoute] int id, [FromBody] Engineer engineer)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    if (id != engineer.EngineerId)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    _context.Entry(engineer).State = EntityState.Modified;

    try
    {
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        if (!EngineerExists(id))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    return NoContent();
}
```

I have 3 models: Engineer.cs, Application.cs, and the join table EngineerApplications.cs.  These tables represent a many to many relationship where engineers have many apps they support and apps have many engineers that support them.

Engineer.cs:

```
public class Engineer
{
    ...Some Stuff Here...

    //Navigation Property
    public ICollection<EngineerApplications> EngineerApplications { get; set; }
}
```

Application.cs:

```
public class Application
{
    ...Some Stuff Here...

    //Navigation Property
    public ICollection<EngineerApplications> EngineerApplications { get; set; }
}
```

EngineerApplications.cs:

```
public class EngineerApplications
{
    public int EngineerId { get; set; }
    public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public Engineer Engineer { get; set; }
    public Application Application { get; set; }
}
```

JSON:

```
[{
    "engineerId": 1,
    "supportedApplications": [{
        "application": {
            "applicationId": 1,
            "engineerApplications": null
        },
        "applicationId": 1,
        "engineer": {
            "engineerId": 1,
            "engineerApplications": null
        },
        "engineerId": 1
    },
    {
        "application": {
            "applicationId": 2,
            "engineerApplications": null
        },
        "applicationId": 2,
        "engineer": {
            "engineerId": 1,
            "engineerApplications": null
        },
        "engineerId": 1
    }]
},
...
]
```

When this JSON hits the PUT method in the back I want the Engineer table to update, but I also want the EngineerApplications and Applications table to update.  Currently only the Engineers table updates.

I am a novice in C#/Web API/EFcore/etc and don't know how I am supposed to do this. I have looked around for solutions, but I couldnt find anything that worked or that was similar enough to my code.

I assume I have to manually update the other 2 tables, but I don't know how to do even that.

Comment: In your put method, retrieve the entity and then apply all changes according to your view model and then invoke SaveChangesMethod in your DbContext instance, that makes sense ?

Comment: At a very high level the logic makes sense. Unfortunately, I do not understand HOW to do those things.  idk how to retrieve an entity, idk how to apply the changes.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, I'll provide one solution assuming some things.

In order to solve your question, you need to perform these steps:

1. Retrieve your entity with childs
2. Set changes for entity
3. Set changes for childs
4. Save changes

Sample code:

```
// PUT: api/Engineers/5
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PutEngineer([FromRoute] int id, [FromBody] Engineer engineer)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    // Retrieve engineer by id
    var entity = await _dbContext.Engineers
        .Include(p => p.EngineerApplications)
        .FirstOrDefault(item => item.EngineerId == id);

    if (entity == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    // Set changes (exclude entity's key)
    entity.FirstName = engineer.FirstName;
    entity.MiddleName = engineer.MiddleName;
    entity.LastName = engineer.LastName;

    // There another ways to check engineer applications,
    //in this case we want to update not add
    // So we don't worry about to check if child if exists or not
    if (engineer.EngineerApplications.Count == entity.EngineerApplications.Count)
    {
        // Apply changes in navigation properties
        for (var i = 0; i < entity.EngineerApplications.Count; i++)
        {
            // Set changes, assuming those values are in engineer instance
            entity.EngineerApplications[i].Active = engineer.EngineerApplications[i].Active;
        }
    }

    try
    {
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
    {
        // Add logging for exception
        return new ObjectResult(entity) { StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError };
    }

    return Ok(entity);
}
```

With that code you'll perform update on your entities.

Regards